# Query how many levels are below a parent in a hierarchy

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursion

I am working with employee data and I think I need to write a recursive query, but I'm only a little familiar with them. I'm struggling to find out how to write a query that identifies how many levels are below a manager.

The data looks like this:

```
    | employee    | manager    |
    |-------------+------------+
    |  employee1  |  employee1 |

    |  employee2  |  employee1 |

    |  employee3  |  employee1 |
    |  employee3  |  employee2 |

    |  employee4  |  employee1 |
    |  employee4  |  employee2 |
    |  employee4  |  employee3 |

    |  employee5  |  employee1 |

    |  employee6  |  employee1 |
    |  employee6  |  employee2 |
...
```

Essentially this portion is telling me:

- `employee1` has 2 levels below, because they manage employee2, who manages employee3.
- `employee2` has 1 levels below
- `employee3` has 1 levels below
- `employee4` has 0 levels below
- `employee5` has 0 levels below
- `employee6` has 0 levels below

Any ideas/tips on how to write this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Introduce a `level` column into your recursive query that is initialized with 1 and increased on every iteration. Then run a `max` over the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select employee, employee as s, 0 as lev
      from t
      union all
      select cte.employee, t.employee, lev + 1
      from cte join
           t
           on t.manager = cte.s and t.manager <> t.employee
     )
select distinct on (employee) employee, lev
from cte
order by employee, lev desc;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=97dab22ca9106e14f19ae7d7fb36d002) is an example in db<>fiddle.

Comment: It is not my post but, thanks for this code. I couldn't manage to do it in time. Could you please explain a bit ? Even with the documentation I have quite a hard time to understand recursive cte.